# JQuery: attaching event data in list

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a list containing some articles with their introtext. On click, I refer to an anchor #article.
The contents of this anchor should be replaced with the article's full text on click.

However, #article always displays the full text of the last element. (row.fulltext points to the last element)
Any ideas?

```
$.each( result, function(i, row) {
    var li = '<li><a href="#article">'+row.introtext+'</a></li>';
    $('#news-list').append(li).on("click", function(event) {
        $("#article-content").html(row.fulltext);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the content of your row.fulltext in a data-fulltext (for example) attribute of your li, and then access it by

```
 $("#article-content").html($(this).data('fulltext'));
```

or

```
$("#article-content").html($(this).attr('data-fulltext'));
```

Or you can also store it in a hidden element linked to your li by id, or by DOM positioning, so as you can access it by DOM traversal or by id.

**EDIT:**

The problem seems to come from event binding (i think the selector is too generic and it binds event multiple time on li.
I would do it like that (span stand for your "result" variable):

```
$(function(){
    $('span').each(function(){
        $this = $(this);
        var $li = $('<li data-fulltext="'+$this.data('fulltext')+'"><a href="#article">'+$this.html()+'</a></li>');
        $('#news-list').append($li);
        $li.on('click',function(){
            $('#article-content').html($(this).data('fulltext'));
        });
    });
});
```

**[Full demo here >> jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9aGmW/)**

Comment: I've stored $('#news-list').append(li).data('fulltext',row.fulltext)
and then used your suggestion.
However, that doesn't solve the problem. I still get the last fulltext item...
I know that I can store an element with its ID, however, this looks to me as a rather dirty solution. There must be a way to directly attach an event inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, that's it! Using the li string as a selector solved the problem.
Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather try ***delegated-events approach***, if you want to attached the `click` event to `li` elements.

```
$('#news-list').append(li).on('click','li a', function(event) {
        $("#article-content").html(row.fulltext);
    });
```

Comment: Hm. No, that's not related to my problem. row.fulltext will be overwritten on every loop, therefore, I need a solution to keep the fulltext associated with the current listitem.

Comment: Ok. can you show the structure of the elements used.  For example: table -> tr -> td... like this.  Can you share it.